# C# TcpListener with ActionScript

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to connect C# with action script so I to try this and it worked and it connected but when i tried to send a do writeUTF I debugged my action script and the console application closed straight away with nothing displayed on it the swf loads and BAM it closes within 1 second

I coded a console application and just added 5 lines to the main void

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3001);
    server.Start();
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
}
```

And I also added this action script to my action script fla file

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3001);
socket.writeUTF("h");
socket.flush();
```

When I added the second line of the action script and the last 2 lines of the C# code it started that bug where it closed straight away. Before it started doing this I received a debug error shown below

```
Unable to read beyond the end of the stream
```

The error occurs on the line it tries to write on the console the reader.ReadString() but now it just closes straight away.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in play on both the ActionScript client and C# server side.

**ActionScript client**

On the ActionScript side, you're immediately writing to the socket before it's connected.  You need to wait for the socket to connect by listening for [`Event.CONNECT`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#CONNECT).

It would also be advisable to listen for `IOErrorEvent` and `SecurityErrorEvent` for error handling and dealing with security sandbox violations and cross domain policies.

```
public var socket:Socket;

public function connect():void {
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3001);
    socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
}

public function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
    socket.writeUTF("h");
    socket.flush();
    socket.close();
}
```

**C# server**

On the C# server side, binary reader uses a [`Read7BitEncodedInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint.aspx) to parse the length of the string.  That 32-bit compressed format integer is incompatible with ActionScript's [`writeUTF()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#writeUTF()) method which uses a 16-bit integer for string length.

For example, change to a StreamReader to see your code functioning.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Any, 3001);
    server.Start ();
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient ();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (client.GetStream (), Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine (reader.ReadLine ());
}
```

You could extend ActionScript's socket class for a custom `writeUTF()`, which would `writeInt()` first followed by `writeUTFBytes()` if you want to retain binary readers.